# Problems exporting document to local google apis

Tags: node.js, file, google-drive-api, export

I'm having some real trouble downloading files from google drive via googleapis node.

This is my current code that I've got working to

```
drive.files.export(
    {
        auth: this.jwtToken,
        fileId: fileId,
        mimeType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
    }, 
    async function (err, file, response) 
    {
        console.log(file.data);
    }
)
```

Out put is text like the following:

```
�0$Ҡċ�E��4���G��[�V�%�;]�4,횕9�M������;
```

��
o���(�* S��Ca�VJ�e\a���}8x%3�a֩�3��L��4f�4�:�<H2�`�ʗ� ���-6�g�����[K������[���M��&zD1��S�����@�ǽ5�b��ظ��w�~���#-�P\ϲ�lt�!Q��M�"�

But when I use the code from the google example as seen here:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads

I get the following errors:

```
TypeError: drive.files.export(...).on is not a function
```

And when I try to save the string from my method then I get a corrupt file when I try to open it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to export Google Document as Microsoft DOCX format using googleapis for Node.js.
- You have already been able to get the file content using Drive API.

#### Issue:

Unfortunately, I think that the script of Node.js in the official document might not be updated. By this, an error occurs. When you are using the latest version of googleapis for Node.js (Now it's `googleapis@59.0.0`.), how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
const fileId = "###";  // file ID of Google Document.
const dest = fs.createWriteStream("###");  // Filename. Google Document is saved as the DOCX format to this file.

drive.files.export(
  {
    auth: this.jwtToken,,
    fileId: fileId,
    mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
  },
  { responseType: "stream" },
  function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    response.data
      .on("end", function () {
        console.log("Done.");
      })
      .on("error", function (err) {
        console.log("Error during download", err);
        return process.exit();
      })
      .pipe(dest);
  }
);
```

#### Note:

- In this answer, it supposes that you are using the latest version of googleapis for Node.js. In the current stage, it's `googleapis@59.0.0`. Please be careful this.
- When you want to download the file except for Google Docs file (Document, Spreadsheet, Slides and so on), please use the get method instead of the export method.

#### Reference:

- [googleapis for Node.js](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you so much for the heads up on the version. I was using version 39.2.0. I'll reinstall and try this sample and see if it works and ill let you know. thanks

Comment: Mate you are a life saver. That is crazy that the repo is out of date like that. That has literally just cost me hours of messing around.

Comment: @TheMan68 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.